# How to filter multiples features on QGIS Atlas?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, filter, atlas

I trying to create an atlas with two different features, but want to show were both have with the same field "ROTA".
I'm trying to use @atlas_featureid = $id on layer 'SetasRotas_dissolve'(line feature).
How could I show the layer 'quadras' the same way, just were the features have the same information?

[image: atlas print].

Comment: QGIS version -  3.12.1-București

Comment: Do you still have this problem or have you find solution ? Here is a possible solution : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380687/qgis-atlas-vs-report-feature-id/394505#394505