# In Atlas how can I put a margin around a feature but also use predefined scales

Tags: qgis, scale, atlas

In QGIS, how can I put a margin around a feature but also use predefined scales in Atlas? I have a feature that fits in the map but very tightly, so I would like QGIS to use a smaller scale to better accommodate the drawing.

Tried to create a buffer around the feature thinking the program would understand that I also want it to appear and so shrink the drawing, but it didn't work. Is there a way to do that?

[image]

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, but you can either choose "Margin around feature" or "Predefined Scale (best fit)" or "Fixed Scale". But not two at the same time. To my understanding two options at the same time cant even work in theory? Please correct me if I understood your question the wrong way.

Comment: Yeah, I wish to use the "Predefined Scale" but also to have a margin around each feature, so it doesn't look too tight in the mapview, as it is shown in the image of the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets take this as an example. Some features in a layer and a second layer buffering these features:

[image]

First go to Project -> Properties and add some suiting scales you wish to use. **The quality of your result will highly depend on this list!**

[image]

Now in your layout go to Atlas tab and change your coverage layer to the buffer. Choose "Hidden coverage layer" if you dont wish to show this buffer on your map:

[image]

Now go back to your map-properties and choose "Predefined Scale (best fit)" within "Controlled by Atlas":

[image]

Here an example (with buffers not hidden to illustrate):

[image]

Take a look at the changeing scalebar on the top-right. It always matches a scale we just pre-defined in our project settings. **The quality of your result is highly dependent on the list of predefined scales available for your project. Alternatively you can also try other buffer sizes.**

Comment: It does answer the question but doesn't work for me. I need it to be the layer with the actual features to be the coverage layer since I have a symbology that depends on it to work. I'll make another post with this particular problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: As your buffer is created from your atlas layer you will get the same attribute table. You can adapt symbology rules on your target layer to get attributes from your buffer layer and verify. Here is an example how to make symbology rules : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380687/qgis-atlas-vs-report-feature-id/394505#394505