# Representing buffer (e.g., +/-10%) around object and displaying predefined "straight" scale in object's representation

Tags: qgis, layouts, atlas, qgis-custom-function

I am working on a mapping project in QGIS with the Atlas feature, and I'm facing a specific challenge. I need to generate map representations of individual features in a way that includes a dynamic buffer zone around each feature, where the buffer size is a percentage (e.g., +/- 10%) of the feature's dimensions AND applying the next predefined scale.

[In Atlas how can I put a margin around a feature but also use predefined scales](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/395074/in-atlas-how-can-i-put-a-margin-around-a-feature-but-also-use-predefined-scales) is related, but i don't want to apply the same layer and not another "buffered" layer as the main atlas object.

[image: Snipped Atlas]

I am aware that the buffer would not be exactely 10% when applying it to the next predefined scale.

Is there a way to do this?
-> perhaps with a custom function in the "buffered size" object?

Comment: So, if a feature + 50 % buffer exceeds e.g. 1:2500 you want to jump to e.g. 1:4000 instead of 1:3000?

Comment: @Erik exactely! This would be great if you had any idea how to do this!

Comment: Create a new layer with the buffer size you want - to make it dynamic, you can create a virtual layer. Hide this layer (uncheck visibility), then use this layer as coverage layer and set percentage to 0%. Don't see why you don't want a buffer layer as this seems to be the easiest solution to me...

Comment: That is the easiest solution, that is right. But it creates a bit of a mess in the project and if multiple person work on the same project, they might get confused. @Babel